# Can I increase the scope of options being displayed in the autocomplete (Content Assist)?

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist

I don't know the name of this functionality, so I think it's better to use an example: imagine you have an object `player` with a `getScore()` method.

If you type `player.sco`, it will present you the attributes and methods that start with "sco", and not the `getScore()` method. I've been using MonoDevelop for a while and it displays any option that has an occurrence of the string you typed, so `getScore()` would be there. Is it possible to set eclipse to do the same?

Comment: I'm on a phone po I'm not able to post a fully answer with all it takes: Since Eclipse 4.2, there is Code Recommenders have been implemented. For this, there is a Java Subword content assist option which dnes exactly what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Eclipse Juno (v4.2), there is a [Code Recommenders](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/) code assist plugin integrated which can do exactly what you want.

By default, only the smart completion is enabled, but in `Window -> Preferences -> Code Recommenders` menu, you can enable Chains and, in your case, [Subwords](http://code-recommenders.blogspot.cz/2011/08/eclipse-subwords-completion-1-here-you.html).

Make sure you also enable Subwords to be shown (`Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced`).

Here's a simple example with `System.setOut()` method that was shown just for `out` substring:

[image: example of Recommenders Subwords]

Answer (score 0):

I looked over Eclipse Content Assist configuration and I do not found anything to change the filter, from "starts with" to "contains" for example.

Its possible to be another way to do that, but, I dont know how to do it.

But, I have a suggestion for you.

Do you know that if you type the initial letters in lower camel case you can get a better result, for example:

In your object `player` you have the `getScore()` method. If you type:

```
player.gS
```

Then use `CTRL + Space` the `getScore()` method will be suggest for you.

Maybe this is not what you wanted, but maybe it helps.